# How to send an email to multiple recipients ?

Tags: sql-server, email, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which sent emails to few recipients. In this I want to send to two differet recipients using ***@copy_recipients***. But I get a syntax error. How to make this work?

**stored procedure code**

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'mail', 
    @recipients = @Mail1,
    @copy_recipients = @Mail2;@Mail3, 
    @body =@body ,
    @subject =@subject
```

Comment: `@Mail2;@Mail3` - right concept, bad implementation. The `;`, being *not* in a string, terminates the SQL statement which leads to invalid syntax.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to add `;` (semicolon) between e-mail addresses using string concatenation:

```
DECLARE @copy_to varchar(max)= @Mail2+';'+@Mail3

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'mail', 
    @recipients = @Mail1,
    @copy_recipients = @copy_to, 
    @body =@body ,
    @subject =@subject
```

You can read MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx#Anchor_1http://)

> [ **@recipients**= ] *'recipients'*
>
> Is a **semicolon-delimited** list of e-mail
>   addresses to send the message to. The recipients list is of type
>   varchar(max). Although this parameter is optional, at least one of
>   @recipients, @copy_recipients, or @blind_copy_recipients must be
>   specified, or sp_send_dbmail returns an error.
>
> [ **@copy_recipients**= ] *'copy_recipients'*
>
> Is a **semicolon-delimited** list
>   of e-mail addresses to carbon copy the message to. The copy recipients
>   list is of type varchar(max). Although this parameter is optional, at
>   least one of @recipients, @copy_recipients, or @blind_copy_recipients
>   must be specified, or sp_send_dbmail returns an error.

Comment: My pleasure! ;)